# Trying to use the sum operator in matplotlib gives an error

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, sum, jupyter-notebook, interactive

So I would like to mention first that I am completely new to basically everything that is linked to Jupyter Notebook, matplotlib and numpy stuff. So that's why I most likely will not be able to express my problem clearly. Therefore I am begging for your patience :) (ah yeah and my English sucks too so...)

Anyways, I am trying to create an interactive plot. Therefore, I want to display the function of the first *n* polynomes of the square wave where the value of *n* can be choosen by using a slider. This is what I got so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (11,4)
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150

from ipywidgets import interact,interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as Widgets


def f(n):

    plt.plot(      np.arange(0,10), 1/pi * sum(  2/(i* pi) * (1- cos(i*pi) ) * sin(i*np.arange(0,10)) for i in range(1,n)   )       ) 
    plt.ylim(-2,2)
interact(f, n= 1)
```

Now, everything works fine until the line where I set my function, so the line with this

plt.plot(np.arange ...)

It gives me the following error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

I already figured out that this has to do with the usage of the *sum()* Operator and using the variable *n* in it. If i don't put *n* in the *sum*, then everything works out nicely and I am getting my graph.

So, the question basically is what I will have to do to make my idea happen.

Thank you for your Responses, I know that my post might be very annoying to some of you because of its style or whatever and I am sorry for that.

Comment: The code would be easier to debug if you assigned some variables.  e.g. `x = np.arange(0,10)`, and `y = 1/pi * sum... sin(i*x)...`, and finally `plot(x,y)`.  Then you can narrow the problem down to the `y` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sum` means you collapse the list of values down to a single value, that's what numpy is telling you - you have 10 `x` values and only 1 `y` value (because you just added them all up). I think what you are meaning to do is create a list of sums, so just move one closing parenthesis (`)`) from after the `for i in range(n)` to before it:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,10), 1/pi * sum(2/(i* pi) * (1- cos(i*pi)) * sin(i*np.arange(0,10))) for i in range(1,n))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick Response. However, after I tried that out, I got the error message that i must put the Generator Expression in parenthesis, so that's what I did. But then, a systax error occured and I have no clue what the error is referring to.

Comment: plt.plot((np.arange(Integer(0),Integer(10)), Integer(1)/pi * sum(Integer(2)/(i* pi) * (Integer(1)- cos(i*pi)) * sin(i*np.arange(Integer(0),Integer(10)))) for i in range(Integer(1),n)))
                                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Rather than putting the generator in parentheses, put it in square brackets to make a list comprehension. See if that works

Comment: I think that this might not be the problem. Square brackets still give me the syntax error, but I have no idea where this is to be found.

Comment: I'm not on a computer right now to try things sorry. I suggest you pull out the creation of the y values to before the plot call, and store them in a variable. Then you'll be able to get a better error hopefully (or it'll work)

Answer (score 0):

So, for those of you who are interested in the answer (probably there are some): I found a nice and simple solution.

The Problem was the fact, that the line

```
interact(f, n= 1)
```

didn't work on its own. Now that I put it like this,

```
interact(f, n =widgets.IntSlider(min=2, max=100, step=1, value=2))
```

so by - most importantly - saying that the slider is supposed to be an IntSlider, everything works just fine!

Thank you for your help anyways! Since I am new on this platform, I don't know how solved questions can be closed, but this one here defenitely can be closed.